# SimpleDateFormat returns strange date with invalid date string

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I try to parse time formating string ,now when I parse string "2014-01-07 95:25:37" , it return a date ,not throw ParseException . who know how to let it throw ParseException . Thanks George .

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.print(  ft.parse("2014-01-07 95:25:37"));
```

output :

```
Fri Jan 10 23:25:37 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the problem is the time : 95:25:37 . Java tries to add this extra time to your days ,hence you are get additional 3 days.

To prevent java from doing so, you can use the following :

```
 ft.setLenient(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setLenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to validate the input date `String`

```
ft.setLenient(false);
```