# Does the java.util.Date object verifies the date validity?

Tags: java, date

I just wrote this unit tests :

```
@Test
public void testGetDateFromString() throws ParseException{
    String date = "52/29/2500";
    Date dateFromString = DateHelper.getDateFromString(date, DateHelper.DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DateHelper.DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT);
    Date dateWithSimpleFormat = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);

    Assert.assertNotNull(dateFromString);
    Assert.assertNotNull(dateWithSimpleFormat);

    Assert.assertTrue(dateFromString.equals(dateWithSimpleFormat));

    System.out.println("dateFromString " + dateFromString);
    System.out.println("dateWithSimpleFormat " + dateWithSimpleFormat);
}
```

And the output is :

```
dateFromString Wed Jun 21 00:00:00 CEST 2502
dateWithSimpleFormat Wed Jun 21 00:00:00 CEST 2502
```

The `DateHelper.DD_MM_YYYY_FORMAT` pattern is `dd/MM/yyyy` and `getDateFromString` is a method that parses a String date to a Date object using `commons-lang` library.

Why des the java.util.Date object verifies the date validity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat returns strange date with invalid date string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018920/simpledateformat-returns-strange-date-with-invalid-date-string)

Comment: You are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes of JSR 310. See the modern approach in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52645379/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);` to make the SimpleDateFormat to validate your input strictly.

You can refer the [setLenient documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) for further understanding. By the definition,

```
Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, 
the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this 
object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);` to enable strict parsing.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");

    String date = "52/29/2500";
    try {
        LocalDate dateWithJavaTime = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);

        System.out.println("dateWithJavaTime " + dateWithJavaTime);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("Invalid date. " + dtpe);
    }
```

The output from this code is:

> Invalid date. java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
>   '52/29/2500' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid
>   values 1 - 12): 29

Please enjoy not only that the validation works, but also the precision of the error message.

Other results:

- For the string `52/11/2500` the result is “Invalid date. java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '52/11/2500' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 52”.
- For the string `29/02/2019` we get “dateWithJavaTime 2019-02-28”, which may surprise. To have this string rejected use

  ```
      DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
              .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
  ```

  Now we get

  > Invalid date. java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
  >   '29/02/2019' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2019'
  >   is not a leap year

  Again enjoy how precise the message is.